# how to grab text after newline and concat each line to make a new one in a text file no clean of spaces, tabs

Tags: bash, grep, text-processing

##### I have a text like this:

```
    Print <javascript:PrintThis();>

  www.example.com

Order Number: *912343454656548 *    Date of Order: November 54 2043

------------------------------------------------------------------------
*Dicders Folcisad:
* STACKOVERFLOW 


    *dum FWEFaadasdd:*   ‎[U+200E]         ‎
STACK OVERFLOW
BLVD OF SOMEPLACENICE 434
SANTA MONICA, COUNTY               
LOS ANGEKES, CALI 90210
(SW)   
*Order Totals:*
Subtotal    Usd$789.75
Shipping    Usd$87.64
Duties & Taxes  Usd$0.00 ‎
Rewards Credit  Usd$0.00
*Order Total *  *Usd$877.39 *

         
*Wordskccds:*
STACKOVERFLOW 
FasntAsia
xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-


*test Method / Welcome Info *

易客满x京配个人行邮税- 运输 + 关税 & 税费 / ADHHX15892013504555636

*Order Number: 916212582744342X*
        
*#*     *Item*  *Price*     *Qty.*  *Discount*  *Subtotal*
1      
Random's Bounty, Product, 500 mg, 100 Rainsd Harrys AXK-0ew5535                   
    Usd$141.92  4   -Usd$85.16  Usd$482.52
2          
Random Product, Fast Forlang, Mayority Stonghold, Flavors, 10 mg,               
60 Stresss CXB-034251        
    Usd$192.24  1   -Usd$28.83  Usd$163.41                
3   
34st Omicron, Novaccines Percent Pharmaceutical, 10 mg, 120 Tablesds XDF-38452     
    Usd$169.20  1   -Usd$25.38  Usd$143.82
                     
    *Extra Discounts:* Extra 15% discounts applied!     Usd$139.37

*Stackoverflox Contact Information :*
*Web: *www.example.com

*Disclaimer:* something made, or service sold through this website,
have not been test by the sweden Spain norway and Dumrug
Advantage. They are not intended to treet, treat, forsee or
forshadow somw clover.
```

I'm trying to grab each line that start with number, then concat second line, and finally third line. example text:

- `1 Random's Bounty, Product, 500 mg, 100 Rainsd Harrys AXK-0ew5535 Usd$141.92 4 -Usd$85.16  Usd$482.52`
- `2 Random Product, Fast Forlang, Mayority Stonghold, Flavors, 10 mg, 60 Stresss CXB-034251 Usd$192.24 1 -Usd$28.83 Usd$163.41` <- 1 line
- `3 34st Omicron, Novaccines Percent Pharmaceutical, 10 mg, 120 Wedscsd XDF-38452 Usd$169.20 1 -Usd$25.38 Usd$143.82` <- 1 lines as first

as you may notices Second line has 3 lines instead of 2 lines. So make it harder to grab.

Because of the `newline` and `whitespace`, the next command only grabs `1`:

```sh
grep -E '1\s.+'
```

also, I have been trying to make it with new concats:

```
grep -E '1\s|[A-Z].+'
```

- But doesn't work, `grep` begins to select similar pattern in different parts of the text

```sh
awk '{$1=$1}1'   #done already
tr -s "\t\r\n\v" #done already
tr -d "\t\b\r"   #done already
```

I'm trying to make a script, so I give as an **ARGUMENT** a not clean **FILE** and then grab the table and select **each** number with their respective data. Sometimes data has 4 lines, sometimes 3 lines. So copy/paste don't work for ME.

Comment: Please add sample input (no descriptions, no images, no links) and your desired output for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Comment: how do you tell if you need to process 2, 3, or n lines?

Answer (score 0):

I think the last line to be joined is the line starting with "Usd". In that case you only need to change the formatting in

```
awk '
  !orderfound && /^[0-9]/ {ordernr++; orderfound=1 }
   orderfound { order[ordernr]=order[ordernr] " " $0 }  
  $1 ~ "Usd" { orderfound = 0 }
  END {
   for (i=1; i<=ordernr; i++) { print order[i] }
  }' inputfile
```